# Issue in django 1.7.2 version while doing makemigrations

Tags: python, django, makemigrations

when created new model and executing makemigrations in django 1.7.2 version

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field u'id' in class
>   'PhotoFeatureImage' clashes with field of similar name from base class
>   'PhotoFeature'

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the migrations and migrate with a new DB.
Check out this link from Django doc [link](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21890)